# Need to make web form that save any change even if not click "SEND"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, dom-events, user-input

In my new site I have form for client that went to contact me.
I don't have much web programming experience so I'm not sure what is the easiest way to do it,

My goal is for example if the client fill his name and phone number, and then decide that there is too much fields to fill (even that it's not must) then he give-up and exit the page,
Then I went to make in such case I will still get his the details that he filled, (name and phone number)
Also, if he fill something and then change or delete, I also went to know.

What is the easiest way to do it?
Is there any open-source PHP base system that can do it?
Even add-on for WordPress.
The person that fill the page, will he know that I do it? it will load each time he move field or something? because I really prefer that it won't

BTW, I'm not going to contact anyone if he not press send, I just went to learn better why I lose leads and maybe maximum to send email question about that.

Comment: You can use ajax in the onChange event of each field. But i don't think its a good thing to do. u are depriving the freedom of a user to choose not to submit there info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ajax and save everytime they change a value in the form by "change, keyup" or something similar like mentioned in the answer before. Since you use Wordpress you can use jquery for that.

It could potentially look something like this. Made 3 different ways to define a field if you are unfamiliar with jQuery, it is a lot like CSS. The serialize does take all your fields and post them to the your_savingfile.php.

```
$('input[name="firstname"], .lastname, #phonenumber').on('keyup', function(){
    saveForm($('#form-id'));
}

var function = saveForm(f) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your_savingfile.php",
        data: f.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#save-notify-div").html('Saved form...');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If I will do it by keyup it will be big bunch of data that I will also find good way to merge without losing data. I think the best way is to save field each time the client move the focus out of it, my experience is mostly in .net (not web) but I'm sure there is focus-off kind of event in JS.

Comment: Also, if I already ask, is it safe to store the data on php file like that? I don't talk about serious hacking attempt, but it's sound easy to get the information if the file is on the server like that. is there any free service that allow me to store such data and is more safe?

Comment: The best way should be to save the data in your database, where the rest of the wordpress install is stored. In what way are you storing your data today? Nothing should be stored in the PHP-file, that file should be used to send the data to your server and store it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to solve your problem would be to update your server when the user moves away from your page. You can do this by attaching a handler to the 'unload' event

```
window.onunload = function(){
    //collect all form field values and make ajax request here
}
```

One thing to remember while doing this is that you cannot receive the server response. It has to be a send and forget approach.

Comment: This sound good, I didn't know there is such event as unload. does it insure that I will get the form as it was when the person left the page without sending? for example if he close the explorer, how so when it's happened? in the closing process? I think I better use something that save each time a filed lose the focus.

Answer (score 0):

actually I can see the answer for this is you to monitor the events(base on your scenario, keypress, keydown, keyup for your fields) of the form elements and then send data via ajax call to your server. You can use jQuery ajax for ease http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/


but take note that this will call multiple requests, which may populate and increase traffic on your server so use it wisely